# compact set real analysis proof need check

Tags: real-analysis

people

Here is a question about the compact set and want to be criticized by people

question

```
Let A = {1/n:n = 1,2,3.......}
show that the set A is not compact by constructing an open cover of A that does not have a finite sub-cover A
```

> 1. show we have to define any reasonable finite sub-cover and show another confer example
> 2. since A=(1,1/2,1/3........0] , it never touch the 0 so
> 3. I choose the small n = 0+έ , and define the finite set as (1,n)
> 4. and counter example can argue that there is always small R exist, so n1 = 0+1/2έ , then my first argument got countered.

I'm not sure this how to argue with this problem

thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your "solution", but try to construct a cover with elements (intervals) covering only one point of $A$.

Comment: hi, njguliyev can you show me how to approach this question?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

$$A\subset\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{3n^n};\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^n}\right)$$
Each of the open intervals contains only one point from $A$. No finite number of such intervals will be able to cover entire $A$.

These intervals are disjoint and constitute an infinite open cover of $A$. No finite sub-cover can cover entire $A$. Hence the set $A$ cannot be compact.